# Are there any good libraries or strategies for testing multithreaded applications in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm curious if anyone has come up with a good strategy for testing multithreaded apps.

I do alot of testing with midje, which is great for testing functions... but I'm not really sure how to test multithreaded code without it looking really hacky:

```
  (fact "the state is modified by a thread call"
    (Thread/sleep 100)
    (check-state-eq *state* nil)
    (Thread/sleep 100)
    (modify-state-thread-call *state* :updated-value)
    (Thread/sleep 100)
    (check-state-eq *state* :updated-value))
```

Sometimes, because of compilation time, my tests fail because a state was not updated in time, so then I have to sleep for longer. Ideally, I would want a way to write something like:

```
  (fact "the state is modified by a thread call"
    (modify-state-thread-call *state* :updated-value) 
     =leads-to=> (check-state-eq *state* :updated-value))
```

and move away from the sleeps. Are there strategies to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `*state*` in this example is one of the clojure reference types, you can add a function that is notified of every change to that object using add-watch: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/add-watch

An approach I might suggest is to use a watch to deliver a promise when the condition is satisfied.

```
(let [check-promise (promise)]
  (add-watch *state* :check-for-updated-value
    (fn [rkey refr _oldval newval]
       (when (some-check newval)
          (remove-watch refr rkey)
          (deliver check-promise true))))
  (modify-state-thread-call *state* :updated-value)
  (deref check-promise 1000 false))
```

This will return true immediately if `*state*` takes on a value that satisfies `some-check` within 1000ms, or after 1000ms if the condition is not met, returns false.

Comment: The problem I have is with having to write in the code to wait a certain length of time. Sometimes because of compilation, the times vary significantly. I like the idea of promises though I'm not too familiar with the concept

Comment: ooh... After looking at the code again... I understand what's going on now. It's very cool

Comment: Yep, it short-circuits and completes as soon as the condition is satisfied. You could easily wrap this up so that you could write (wait-for some-ref some-predicate timeout)

Or you could leave the timeouts out if you're okay with the test hanging forever when you write a bug ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Crate's response, I've created a `wait` function:

```
(defn return-val [p ms ret]
  (cond (nil? ms) (deref p)
        :else (deref p ms ret)))

(defn wait
  ([f rf] (wait f rf nil nil))
  ([f rf ms] (wait f rf ms nil))
  ([f rf ms ret]
     (let [p (promise)
           pk (hash-keyword p)
           d-fn (fn [_ rf _ _]
                  (remove-watch rf pk)
                  (deliver p rf))]
       (add-watch rf pk d-fn)
       (f rf)
       (return-val p ms ret))))
```

Its usage is:

```
(defn threaded-inc [rf]
  (future
    (Thread/sleep 100)
    (dosync (alter rf inc)))
  rf)

(def arf (ref 0))
(deref (threaded-inc arf)) ;=> 0

(dosync (ref-set arf 0))
(deref (wait threaded-inc arf)) ;=> 1
```